# Google Script - Timeout and Simplifying

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using a Google script for some time now. The purpose of the script is to unhide or hide certain rows within three tabs when a drop down is selected for hide/unhide. I potentially have two things I want to solve for and can't find any helpful information out there on the interwebs:

1) I think the script runs in order of operations. So when the tab one drop down is selected it has immediate results because that's the first "layer" of the script. The second tab is slower because it's the second "layer" of the script, and the third tab takes quite a while because it's the third "layer". Is there a way to streamline this script to make tab functionality equally as fast?

2) On the third tab, it seems as though the script will time out. All rows will unhide, but when you go in to hide them through the drop down, it will stop on a certain row. It fully works however if you go to the script and manually run it. Below is the script I have been using (*I deleted out a lot of rows below otherwise it would be quite long*):

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("TX MD 2017");           
  var row = s.getRange('C2').getValues();                         
s.showRows(1);
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(row[i] == 'hide') 
     { s.hideRows(5);
       s.hideRows(7); 
       s.hideRows(9);} 

     else if(row[i] == 'unhide'){s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange());} 
}      
s = ss.getSheetByName("DC MD 2017");           
  row = s.getRange('C2').getValues();                         
s.showRows(1);
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(row[i] == 'hide') 
     { s.hideRows(6);
       s.hideRows(7);
       s.hideRows(9); }                           
     else if(row[i] == 'unhide'){s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange());} 
                                }
s = ss.getSheetByName("ATL MD 2017");           
row = s.getRange('C2').getValues();   
s.showRows(1);
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(row[i] == 'hide') 
     {s.hideRows(6);
       s.hideRows(7);
       s.hideRows(9);}                           
     else if(row[i] == 'unhide'){s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange());} 
                                }
}
```

Comment: Since `c2` is a single cell, I think `for` is not necessary. Also you called `ss.getDataRange()` three times, but its value doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange());
```

Should be:

```
s.showRows(1, s.getLastRow());
```

With `s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange())` you are getting the data range of the entire spreadsheet.
The documentation states:

> a range consisting of all the data in the spreadsheet

That's probably why the code is running so slow.

The code can be consolidated to:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var arrayOfRowsToHide,i,j,k,L,objectOfSettings,row,s,ss;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                       

  objectOfSettings = {
    "TX MD 2017":[5,7,9],
    "DC MD 2017":[6,7,9],
    "ATL MD 2017":[6,7,9]
  }

  for (k in objectOfSettings) {//Loop through all settings
    s.showRows(1);
    s = ss.getSheetByName(k);//get this sheet by name
    row = s.getRange('C2').getValues();
    Logger.log('row: ' + row)
    L = row.length;//The number of rows to check

    arrayOfRowsToHide = objectOfSettings[k];//Get array of row numbers

    for (i=0; i<L; i++) {//Loop through all rows in the data from getValues()
      if(row[i] === 'hide') {
        for (j=0;j<arrayOfRowsToHide.length;j++) {//hide all rows
          s.hideRows(arrayOfRowsToHide[j]);
        }
        break;//If this row has a status of "hide" then hide rows and quit
      } else if (row[i] === 'unhide') {
        s.showRows(1, s.getLastRow());//show all rows in the sheet
        break;//continue to next sheet
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I put in place s.showRows(1, s.getLastRow()) and it seems to be going faster. I'll work to put in place the consolidation, but may take a bit to get over the learning curve. Thanks again.